# grep 2 words seperated by either space(s) and/or tab(s)

Tags: shell, grep

I have multiple table definitions extracted in files (one definition per file) and I am trying to get a specific property from the table definition. The table property can be SET or MULTISET and the table definition can be like

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE WEB_APP_OWN_TABLES.VARS_WRK ,NO FALLBACK ,
```

OR

```
CREATE SET TABLE WEB_APP_OWN_TABLES.VARS ,NO FALLBACK ,
```

There can be multiple spaces and/or tabs between the words CREATE and MULTISET/SET

There can be multiple spaces and/or tabs between the words MULTISET/SET and TABLE

the number of spaces and/or tabs between the words can vary with each definition. I used the command below to get the property but it can give me column names such as "CREATE_BY_TABLE". Is there a better way to do this?

```
*egrep -i "\<CREATE\>\*.\*\<TABLE\>" WEB_APP_OWN_TABLES~VARS_WRK.sql | egrep -i "SET|MULTISET"*
```

SAMPLE TABLE DEFINITION:

```
*
CREATE SET TABLE DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP2
     (
      databasename VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      tablename VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      currentperm BIGINT,
      peakperm BIGINT,
      collectdate DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      collecttime INTEGER)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( databasename ,tablename ,collectdate ,
collecttime );
*
```

Comment: Can you show sample input, the result of your command and the result you want? When you `grep -i "SET"` you will find MULTISET too.

Comment: *CREATE SET TABLE <DATABASNAME>.<TABLENAME>,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP2
     (
      databasename VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      tablename VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      currentperm BIGINT,
      peakperm BIGINT,
      collectdate DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      collecttime INTEGER)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( databasename ,tablename ,collectdate ,
collecttime );*

Comment: The file might have the word SET at other locations as well like in the comment above

Comment: Hi Raza, I hoped to see the sample output as a part of your question (that you can Edit). AFAIK you want `egrep -i "CREATE.*SET.*TABLE" WEB_APP_OWN_TABLES~VARS_WRK.sql` but I can not test is with your sample input and compare my results with your exampla output (requirements).

Answer (score 0):

The following (extended) regex should do the match the requirements

```
egrep -i 'create[ \t]+(set|multiset)[ \t]+table' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

We used the command below to get the desired result

```
grep -i -e "\<CREATE\>[[:blank:]]\<MULTISET\>[[:blank:]]\<TABLE\>" -i -e "\<CREATE\>[[:blank:]]\<SET\>[[:blank:]]\<TABLE\>" ${file}|awk '{print $2}'
```